# Why does this openmp code gives segmentation fault?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to execute an OpenMP code and have been successful in doing so. However I have a doubt regarding the statement `#pragma omp parallel`.

Consider these two code snippets:

```
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(my_amax) 
{
    for (i=0; i<MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
        #pragma omp for
        for (j=0; j<MATRIX_DIM; j++) {
            my_amax = abs_max(my_amax, A[i][j], B[i][j]);
            #pragma omp critical 
            {
                if(fabs(amax)<fabs(my_amax))
                    amax=my_amax;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
for (i=0; i<MATRIX_DIM; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(my_amax) 
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (j=0; j<MATRIX_DIM; j++) {
            my_amax = abs_max(my_amax, A[i][j], B[i][j]);
            #pragma omp critical 
            {
            if (fabs(amax)<fabs(my_amax))
                amax=my_amax;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference in the code is the position of the parallel part. The first code always gives me segmentation error, while the second code executes perfectly. Why is that so?

I know that `#pragam omp parallel` spawns the required threads, but since the next `i` for loop is not declared as parallel, it should not be a problem i.e the `i` part should get executed sequentially while the `j` iterations which are actually parallelized will execute in parallel. What does exactly happens in the first case with the `i` iterations?

Comment: Why are you implementing a max reduction by hand? OpenMP supports reductions (and the implementation is likely smarter than yours...)

Comment: If you're going to implement min/max by] hand (e.g. for OpenMP 2.0 with MSVC) then at least create private min/max values for each thread and only using critical per thread and not per iteration.

Comment: @JimCownie This is a good question, i asked myself too. But if one want's a crossplattform solution it needs to be done by hand, since MVSC doesn't support th min/max reduction clauses... (Even not in Visual Studio 15 or mvsc14 ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I can see, you forgot to declare `i` private in the first case. Therefore, `i` is updated quite randomly by the various threads executing the corresponding loop, leading to out of bound access to arrays `A` and `B`.

Just try to add `private(i)` to your `#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(my_amax)` directive and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it worked. However, i never declared the i loop to execute in parallel. Until this point i only asked spawned the required number of threads. Won't i get executed in serial in this case ?

Comment: Yes and no: the `i` loop being inside the `parallel` section, it is executed by all the threads. However, since there is no `omp for` directive decorating it, the work isn't shared by the threads and iteration are not distributed. So all threads are iterating on the whole span of `i` iterations.